# VSphere connect guest os to internet

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vmware-vsphere, vsphere-client

Having a VSphere 6 host which is installed on machine in our private network.
VSphere 6 host IP is 192.68.0.40.
Our getaway router to Internet is on 192.168.0.1.
I can connect to VSphere 6 host from other computers on network (for example from Windows with Windows VSphere client)

On VSphere host is installed virtual machine with Ubuntu 14.04.

How to setup networking on virtual machine (which is guest machine on my VSphere host) so I can connect to Internet?

Guest OS uses virtual switch which is connected to vmnic as on picture.

[Guest OS is connected to vmnic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqAnW.png)

It is not clear to me what IP address and getaway I should enter on my guest OS so I could connect to outside world?

[how to configure ip addresses on guest os](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4wNG.png)

Comment: Have you had any training whatsoever or done any research?

Comment: Have gone through basic videos and theory, now reading books... however it would be really helpful if anyone can help me as some of the features are not clear to me...

Comment: Please read our help pages, they explain what and who this site is for - and what and who it's not for.

Answer (score 0):

You should enter the same netmask and gateway as any other computer in your network, what you see there is the VM network, which is coupled directly to your internal network. The different port groups allow you to put the ESXi management interface in a separate network, but the default is to have management and the default VM Network on the same untagged VLAN.